# О слове "классный"

Tags: этимология, жаргон

Интересно, каким образом прилагательное "классный" в сленговом употреблении приобрело смысл "хороший" в превосходной степени,  "замечательный "?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Таким же образом, как слово "качественный" приобрело значение высокого (а не низкого) качества.
Кстати, в XIX веке было наоборот: например, слово "качества" применительно к человеку означало дурные качества, пороки.

Но "классный" и не в сленговом, а в обычном употреблении означает именно "высококлассный": классная команда, классный игрок, классный программист и т.п. А сленговое значение развилось из обычного, они очень близки, практически одинаковы.